# renaming the .bmp files using rename command

Tags: linux, shell

I have many bmp files in a folder and I want to rename it, soomething like

abc.bmp bcd.bmp cde.bmp

to

abc_hello.bmp bcd_hello.bmp cde_hello.bmp

using rename command and I and not able to do it any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can say:

```
rename 's/(\.bmp$)/_hello$1/' *.bmp
```

in order to rename the files.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on testing:

```
rename .bmp _hello.bmp *.bmp
```

Answer (score 0):

if `rename` refers to `prename` command from `perl` package then to rename `xxx.bmp` to `xxx_hello.bmp`, run:

```
rename 's/.*\K(?=\.bmp$)/_hello/' *.bmp
```